# Is there any option to write a code in javascript on Google Sheets scripts or in others program that will do some action on Add-ons tool?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I am trying to automatically refresh report from add-ons tool on Google Sheet once a day using js or another program.

I was trying to record macro but it only return - showBar() on script and doesn't really do anything:

```
function UntitledMacro() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  showBar();
};
```

Comment: What does the add-on  tool produce? What does showBar() produce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apps Script can't execute key strokes, or mouse actions, in the add-on sidebar or dialog boxes.  That `showBar()` function name is the function name in the add-on, which the macro recorded, but if you try to execute that add-on function name from the macro, you'll get an error message.  So, when you recorded the macro, it detected that you clicked the add-on menu, and choose to open the sidebar, and the macro recorded the function name from the add-on, but even so, your code can't run an add-on function.

There is no way for an add-on to directly allow your Apps Script code to trigger a function in the add-on code.  If you are trying to programmatically navigate the add-on menu, and the add-on user interface, you can't do that with Apps Script.

The developer of the add-on could provide a setting for a time of day in the sidebar or dialog box, that you could use to save a time of day setting, and then the add-on would need to install a time based trigger.  If *you* install a time based trigger, your trigger can't access the add-on function names.

There are programs that can work from your computer, that can execute key strokes, and mouse actions, but you'd be opening up your computer to security risks possibly, and your computer would need to be on, and the spreadsheet open.